# Qt get system 32bit or 64 bit info?

Tags: windows, qt, 32bit-64bit

I am writing a software using Qt. One of my task is to judge whether Windows OS is 32bit or 64bit, and then do the following operations according this fact.

However, when I was trying "**QSysInfo::WordSize**", it always return 32 while I was actually running on Windows 7-64 bit OS. 
I also tried

```
#ifdef _WIN32
return 32;
#elif _WIN64
return 64;
```

This also returns 32.

Actually Qt is 32bit in my system. Is that the problem?
How can I get the actual word size of Windows?

Thanks

Comment: _WIN32 is defined for both 32 and 64 bit windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would call [`GetNativeSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340.aspx) and check the value of the [`wProcessorArchitecture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958.aspx) field.

The `_WIN32` and `_WIN64` macros are, like all macros, evaluated at compile time. They tell you about the architecture of your executable file rather than the architecture of the system on which the executable runs. That latter information, the information that you want, can only be determined at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

QSysInfo::WordSize only tells you if the application is **compiled** on a 32-bit platform or a 64-bit platform. So, yes, in a way being compiled using a 32-bit Qt will return a word size of 32.

For your case, you might want to check **[IsWow64Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in any c++ environment, including Qt's, on any system that doesn't use "segment registers" (IOW, has a properly flat memory space):

```
uint32_t archwidth = sizeof(int *);    // arch width in bytes
uint32_t archbits  = 8 * archwidth;    // arch width in bits
```

The mechanism here is:

On a 64-bit architecture (like the XEON) the CPU will use 8 byte (64-bit) pointers, and so `archwidth` will return **8**; and `archbits` is then **8*8**, or **64**.

On a 32-bit architecture (like the 68000) the CPU will use 4 byte (32-bit) pointers, and so `archwidth` will return **4**; and `archbits` is then **4*8**, or **32**.

On a 16-bit architecture (like the 6809) the CPU will use 2 byte (16-bit) pointers, and so `archwidth` will return **2**; and `archbits` is then **2*8**, or **16**.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Q_PROCESSOR_WORDSIZE](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/global/qprocessordetection.h?h=dev&id=4744f31e59711a407ffaf2db725711aec41bc134#n186) (or [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/global/qprocessordetection.h?h=dev&id=4744f31e59711a407ffaf2db725711aec41bc134#n214)). I'm surprised it's not documented because it's not in a private header (QtGlobal) and is quite handy.

It could be more preferable for some use cases because it doesn't depend on processor architecture. (e.g. it's defined the same way for x86_64 as well as arm64 and many others)

Example:

```
#include <QtGlobal>
#include <QDebug>

int main() {
#if Q_PROCESSOR_WORDSIZE == 4
    qDebug() << "32-bit executable";
#elif Q_PROCESSOR_WORDSIZE == 8
    qDebug() << "64-bit executable";
#else
    qDebug() << "Processor with unexpected word size";
#endif
}
```

or even better:

```
int main() {
    qDebug() << QStringLiteral("%1-bit executable").arg(Q_PROCESSOR_WORDSIZE * 8);
}
```